# Cloud Datastore Key fromUrlSafe() not compiling

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm attempting to create a Key object which is based of a known URL-safe key. From the [API](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.32.0/apidocs/index.html), it looks like I should use

```
Key k = fromUrlSafe(URL_safe_key);
```

with the import statement

```
import com.google.cloud.datastore.*;
```

However, when compiling (I'm using Maven in the App Engine shell), the import statement loads properly but an error saying the method is not found appears:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol:   method fromUrlSafe(java.lang.String)
```

What is wrong with the code, or is there a different method I should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, you can never import "local methods" that aren't part of a class by importing a module. fromUrlSafe has to either be an instance or static method of a class you imported from com.google.cloud.datastore.

In this case, [fromUrlSafe](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.32.0/apidocs/com/google/cloud/datastore/Key.html#fromUrlSafe-java.lang.String-) is a static method from the [Key](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.32.0/apidocs/com/google/cloud/datastore/Key.html) Class, so your code should instead read:

```
Key k = Key.fromUrlSafe(URL_safe_key);
```